# How do I request that previously taken classes be counted toward my current program?

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor, grades, evaluation

I'm in need of some advice. I am a nontraditional student coming back to school for a degree in nursing. Before I initially left school I only had 2 prerequisites that I still needed to fill. Now I'm being told that I have 4 because I have to retake A&P 1 and 2 with cadavers.

I previously obtained B's in both sections. Is there a proper way to approach the chair or coordinator to a program and respectfully ask for the two classes I've already taken to be reconsidered as fulfillment for the A&P they want me to take now? The material is basically the same and quite frankly I would like to avoid repeating something I've already done well in so that I can move on faster and spend my money taking classes I have not had yet. This feels like a step back.

Comment: Were you given a reason why these are not counted now?

Comment: You've answered your own question with the [tag:advisor] tag - talk to your academic advisor.  They can tell you how the department typically handles such cases, explain the reasoning, look at the rest of your record, and will typically be the one to approve an exception if they believe it is warranted.  They can also tell you how to petition for an exception if you disagree.

Comment: Thank you. I did sit down with an academic advisor before registering for my classes. She wouldn't elaborate on the reasoning accept to say that the material was different. Looking through the material they are using to teach now it all looks the same as what I previously took.

Comment: Sounds like the "advisor" you spoke to just has a standard list of excuses to read from : "the material is different"... It may be worthwhile speaking to one of the lecturers who teaches the subject for their input - I had to do this as the "advisor" I spoke to said I had to do a 4-week course at the end of my first semester (welding etc) and I said I knew how to weld... Spoke to the lecturer and within 5 minutes I was exempt... And., yes, I was a "non-traditional" . ie mature student...

Comment: No reason was given beyond time limit. The material hasn't changed.

Answer (score 3):

> Now I'm being told that I have 4 because I have to retake A&P 1 and 2 with cadavers.

While I find blanket condemnations of the passive voice to be misguided, this is a case where such an objection is well-founded. *Who* told you you have to retake them?

There are two main options. One is to go the professor in charge of the course. Go to office hours, and tell them about the courses you previously took. If you took the courses. Ask them what sort of discretion they have as far as granting course credit. For instance, Sometimes a professor can grant credit based on a course challenge exam. If they don't have discretion, ask them who does.

The other option is to talk with the chair of the department. Seeing them in person would probably be be best, but if they don't have office hours or other opportunities to see them, you can email them. As far as how to "respectfully" ask: really, the main thing is just to present it as inquiry rather than a request, and definitely try to avoid giving the impression that you feel entitled to an affirmative response. Showing a willingness for a compromise, such as taking the final exam for the course in lieu of taking the whole course, rather than expecting to have the requirement completely waived, also helps.

Comment: Okay so I did go and speak to the head of the nursing program. She told me that I could drop the A&P I'm currently in and take the exam that would allow me to bypass retaking A&P parts 1 and 2. Hopefully I do well enough. I appreciate the advice I was given here.